# including a css file in html

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code for a simple dynamic menu and im trying to include a css file:

```
<?php
    // Get current page file name
    $page = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
  </head>
<body>
 <h1>NTUA Library</h1>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" <?php if ($page == "index.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.php" <?php if ($page == "resume.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="photography.php" <?php if ($page == "photography.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php" <?php if ($page == "about.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php" <?php if ($page == "contact.php") echo 'class="current"' ?>>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

This code is inside a file named menu.php in a directory with this path:`C:/xampp/htdocs/php-beginner-crud-level-1/`
The css file is in the same directory too.
However changing the css code brings no change to the menu.In window's dev options in network tab for the css file there is Status Code: 304 Not Modified.
What am I missing?

Comment: What about `href="./style.css"`? Do you see the content of the css file in the dev tools?

Comment: As @dan1st suggests, perhaps check if you can see the content by explicitly visiting the URL of the CSS file and if the modifications are present. This doesn't seem like a caching issue on your browser, but for safety sake, try incognito or private browsing and let us know if the issue persists?

Comment: Could be wrong CSS, but we can't see that.